# Magento code error on different PHP setup

Tags: php, magento, mage

I have the following problem. After moving a website from the old to the new server, the page stops rendering at this point of the code:

```
echo (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(),
'image')->keepFrame(false)->resize(1024);
```

Is there a missing PHP library?

Comment: Read error logs, Luke.

Comment: I added the following code right before. Php errors should be visible then, right? 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: probably - yes. But I would trust error logs more

Comment: All error logs are empty. Though, if I throw an error it gets logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be a memory issue. 128M isn't enough for magento!

Answer (score 0):

Try using just `echo (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(),
'image');`
see if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is that the first image reference on the page?

Try flushing your Magento pre-genreeate image cache: `System > Cache Management > Flush Catalog Images Cache`